# Is it possible to use external jars via @grab from inside the Jenkins groovy postbuild plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to send some specific notifications (REST API) back to our server, which triggered our Jenkins build jobs via REST API. For this, I am about to include a jar of our own, which has a lot of convenience methods in it.
I am able to use the jars inside the Groovy Script by utilizing @Grab, that's fine.

But it doesn't seem to work from within Groovy Postbuild Plugin.
It even doesn't recognize referenced script files from within another package, which is next to the script file.

Is there a workaround? How can I send my specific notification using java or groovy and the methods provided in our own jar? Do I need to write a Jenkins Plugin for this (hope not). Thanks in advance, Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually recommend to changing your jobs over to Jenkins Declarative pipeline. Then you can use the post handling built into the Jenkins pipeline language. You then have some options. You could use the pipeline steps provided by the HTTP Request plugin to call REST APIs,  create a Java tool to call your REST APIs using your Jar library (install as a custom tool which can be used from pipeline) or write a custom plugin to provide the pipeline steps. If you decide to write a plugin have a look at the Webhook Step plugin for how to do it - https://github.com/jenkinsci/webhook-step-plugin. Your best bet might be a custom Java command line tool called  from a pipeline shell step (sh or bat) depending on the agent / slave OS you use.